# passing struct to pthread in c not working. Attempt to access passed struct results in Error: expression must have struct or union type

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I am writing a multi-threaded program that reads in a file of matrices and creates threads that multiply each row of 2 matrices together.  I managed to get everything to work properly using only a single thread, but when I tried to create multiple threads simultaneously, I ran into problems.  First, I am storing the result matrices in a global struct containing an array of struct that contains an array of matrix values. (ex. struct matrixArray.array -> struct matrix.array). When my function that was being called by pthread_create ran, my global matrixArray lost all of its data.  So, I tried to pass the matrixArray into the function called by pthread_create.  However, I keep getting the error: expression must have struct or union type.  This is when I try to access the struct inside the function being called, despite the fact I am declaring it as struct matrixArray.

Here are my structures:

```
typedef struct matrix{

    int rows;
    int cols;
    int multRow; // The "MULTIPLIED ROW" This is for determing which row the current thread needs to use for multiplication. This only applies for Matrix A in each set.
    int size;
    int set; // This is for which set the matrix belongs to.
    char letter; // This is for labeling the matrices A B and C
    int * array;
    unsigned int * threadID; // Array containing the thread ids that are used to create the result

} matrix;


typedef struct matrixArray{

    int size;
    matrix * array;

} matrixArray;
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    pthread_t * tid; /* the thread identifier */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of attributes for the thread */
    int i; // Counter
    int aIndex; // Index of the current 'A' matrix being multiplied.
    int rows,cols;

    // Checke to make sure we have the correct number of arguments supplied
    // when running the program.
    if(argc < 1){
            printf("Error: You did not provide the correct number of arguments.\n\n");
            return 0;
    }

    // Read the file and create the matrices
    readFile();


    // Initialize the result matrix before we start creating threads that use it.
    mtxResults = newMatrixArray();

    // Get the default attributes
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    // Set the current set to be mutliplied to 1
    currentSet = 1;

    // Create a new matrixArray to pass to the threads
    //struct matrixArray *mtxPassed = malloc(sizeof(struct matrixArray));
    struct matrixArray *mtxPassed = newMatrixArray();
    memcpy(mtxPassed, &mtxResults, sizeof(struct matrixArray));

    // Allocate size of tid array based on number of threads
    tid = malloc(threads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    // Create the threads.
    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++){
            //pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, runner, argv[1]);
            pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, runner, mtxPassed);

            // Increment currentSet when the current row evalutated
            // in the current set is equal to the total number of rows available.
            aIndex = ((currentSet * 2) - 2);

            if(mtx.array[aIndex].multRow == mtx.array[aIndex].rows){
                    currentSet++;
            }
    }

    // Wait for threads to finish
    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++){
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    // Print the matrices
    //printMatrices();

} // End of main()
```

And here is the function runner, being called by pthread_create:

```
// The thread will begin control in this function
void *runner(void *param)
{

    struct matrixArray *mtxA = newMatrixArray();
    mtxA = (struct matrixArray *)param;

    printf("mtxPassed.size = %i\n",mtxA.size);

    // Do the matrix multiplication for a single row
    matrixMultiply(currentSet, (unsigned int)pthread_self(), mtxA);

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

Originally, the error was occurring when I passed the mtxA structure to matrixMultiply function, but I have since tried accessing it inside runner directly to see if it worked there.  It still is not.
I get the error at "printf("mtxPassed.size = %I\n",mtxA.size);"  Instead of the first 2 lines of runner, I have also tried "struct matrixArray *mtxA = (struct matrixArray *)param;"  That did not work either.

Here is the error:

```
[nsltg2@lewis assign2]$ cc -pthread -lpthread assign2.c
assign2.c(602): error: expression must have struct or union type
  printf("mtxPassed.size = %i\n",mtxPassed.size);
                             ^
```

I would really appreciate any help you can offer.  Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe you should use `->` insead of `.` to access structure member via pointer

Comment: Hmm, that did seem to fix the error with the type, however, it still isn't passing the data that was in my global structure. Any ideas how to get the data from my global structure to work inside my runner function?

Comment: Your thread proc leaks memory in the first two lines. This isn't Java. And in your main proc: `memcpy(mtxPassed, &mtxResults, sizeof(struct matrixArray));` You're copying from memory you don't own. The `&mtxResults` parameter is wrong. it should be `mtxResults` and in fact, should not be there in the first place. You should be copy-constructing `mtxPassed`. Given all of this and the definition you have for `class matrixArray` you're outright-violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) as well. In short, most of this is wrong.

Comment: Also, what is newMatrixArray();? You probably meant to do a malloc there unless you have a function with name newMatrixArray() that returns a malloced value.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I had found that stuff on other sites, and wasn't exactly sure what it was supposed to be doing. I did just figure out why my global struct lost its data.  I was reinitializing it after I had already filled it.  Taking out the line "mtxResults = newMatrixArray()" in the main function fixed my problem of missing data.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, newMatrixArray() is a function that returns a malloced value. Although, I didn't need it at that location in main.